# Execute a bunch of commands in one fell swoop with ADO.NET

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a series of T-SQL DELETE FROM TABLE and INSERT statements to run. I am using plain ADO.NET (and not the entity framework). Is there a way I could execute all of these statements in one go rather than create a new SqlCommand object for each of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = 
    @"DELETE FROM foo; 
      INSERT INTO foo (name) VALUES ('name1'); 
      INSERT INTO foo (name) VALUES ('name2');
    ";
```

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I meant to ask if I could do.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a single SqlCommand with CommandType.Text to combine all the delete statements together in to a single block. Although it is possible to run both the INSERT and DELETE statements together, it may be easier to batch like commands if you want paramaterized queries.

**Edit**

I was going to add a code sample of how to create a batched parameterized query, but if other answer is all that you need, then I will leave it alone for now.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I meant to ask if I could do.

Comment: Thanks, Calgary Coder. Your answer is actually just as good as the other one. I wish I could give your answer a green checky, too. :-(